# Upgrading SQL Server 2000 to 2005 or 2008 - DTS to SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, upgrade, dts

Our office uses SQL Server 2000, and by and large it has served our needs well. I'm looking into the possibility of upgrading to SQL 2005 or 2008 because of the new features not found in 2000 (when I saw Index usage statistics which told me which Indexes were the most used and which were never used, that blew me away).

I'm not too concerned with how to move the databases from 2000 to 2005 or 2008 - I can just take a full backup and then restore the backup to the new sql installation. What concerns me are the existing DTS packages. We have dozens of them that we rely on every day. How difficult/easy is it to convert the existing DTS packages to SSIS? What are some of the 'gotchas' that I have to look out for?

Answer (score 7):

Doing a backup & restore to do a database server upgrade has many gotcha's.  It's best to do an in-place upgrade (you might want to take a full backup of the server first) & let the MS installer do the work. 
2005 supports 2000 DTS packages as Legacy so there's no need to learn SSIS & convert all your packages unless you have the time & there isn't too many.

As for the backup & restore upgrade, don't forget about:

1. logins, you'll need transfer these,
   see [KB246133](http://ttp://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/246133) for more details
2. Any user and role permissions given
   to system databases will need to be
   re-created or transferred
3. linked server or remote servers will need to be re-setup
4. SQL Server Agent Jobs  need to be exported-imported
5. Any Extended stored procedures need
   to be re-created
6. Replication will need to be re-setup
7. Log shipping will need to be
   re-setup & the standby server also
   upgraded

Comment: Link to KB246133 in answer is dead / invalid.

Answer (score 6):

There is a migration tool for DTS packages, but I wouldn't use it. SSIS is *so* much better than DTS that you should:

1. Learn about SSIS. Get comfortable with it. Rejoice at having actual control flow.
2. Take the time to understand and document your existing DTS packges while you've still got the environment they're written for.
3. Use that understanding to write equivalent SSIS packages.

This idea will make no sense to you if you don't know SSIS. For instance, I was just thinking about how I used to have to do loops in DTS - that whole business with finding and modifying the precedence constraint you wanted to loop back to.

SSIS actually has a For Loop container that can loop over a set of numbers, over the rows in a rowset, over files in a folder, etc. No hacks with precedence constraints and little hidden scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Out DTS packages are VERY simple - they all started out as Import or Export tasks I built using the Import/Export wizard, and I simply saved them as DTS packages. I'll check out using the migration tool vs. writing new equivalent packages. Once again, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5):

DTS packages can still be run as usual in 2008 as long as Backwards Compatibility is installed.  Here's the link to [upgrading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768544.aspx) which uses a wizard.

Comment: I agree this is a good short-term fix, but you really need to start moving them to SSIS. Make a schedule of what you are going to convert and if you have any reason to adjust an existing package, take that opportunity to convert it even if it is ahead of the schdule. Create any new packages in SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a tool from Pragmatic Works called DTS xChange. It handles most of the migration and helps you get on with your job. You'll have other opportunities to learn SSIS on new stuff but you need to probably wrap up your project. It can be downloaded at http://www.pragmaticworks.com